# Salesforce Visualforce Bar Chart problem

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-charting

I am developing a bar chart on visual force page, the data source for this chart is from a object which contains two fields first one is “Name”(text) and second one is “Value”(Decimal); I would like to show the chart as following picture:-

[image: Desired Output]

And I write the everything, Apex controller, visual force page, But didn’t get such output, I don’t know where’s I am making mistake, Please see the source code below:-

------ Visual force Page ------

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController"  showHeader="true" showChat="false" standardStylesheets="true">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Annual Recurring Revenue">
            <apex:form >
                <apex:panelGroup >
                    <apex:chart name="AnnualRecurringRevenue"
                                data="{!AnnualRecurrRevenue}"
                                width="500" height="400"
                                theme="Green"
                                colorSet="#156F9E,#FF9123,#6BAE4A,#424242,#A4A4A4">

                        <apex:legend position="right" />

                        <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" grid="true"                              
                                   title="$(Millions)" 
                                   fields="QuantityValue"
                                   steps="10">
                            <apex:chartLabel />
                        </apex:axis>

                        <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" grid="false"
                                   title="Quarter"
                                   fields="QuantityName">
                            <apex:chartLabel/>
                        </apex:axis>

                        <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" stacked="false"
                                        xField="QuantityName"
                                        yField="QuantityValue">
                            <apex:chartTips rendererFn="doRenderAnnualRecurringRevenue" />
                        </apex:barSeries>
                    </apex:chart>
                </apex:panelGroup>
            </apex:form>
        </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>
```

------ Apex Controller ------

```
public with sharing class ChartController {
    public List<AnnualRecurringRevenue> getAnnualRecurrRevenue() {
            return getAnnualRecurrRevenueItems();
    }
    public static List<AnnualRecurringRevenue> getAnnualRecurrRevenueItems() {
        List<AnnualRecurringRevenue> AnnualRecurrRevenueItems = new List<AnnualRecurringRevenue>();

        List<Accelerate_Console__c> dataItems = [SELECT Quantity_Name__c, Quantity_Value__c FROM Accelerate_Console__c ORDER BY Name Asc];
            for (Accelerate_Console__c dataSO : dataItems) {
                AnnualRecurringRevenue AnnualRecRevenue = new AnnualRecurringRevenue (dataSO.Quantity_Name__c,
                                                             dataSO.Quantity_Value__c);
                AnnualRecurrRevenueItems.add(AnnualRecRevenue);
            }
            return AnnualRecurrRevenueItems;
        }
    public class AnnualRecurringRevenue {
        public String QuantityName { get; set; }        
        public Decimal QuantityValue { get; set; }

        public AnnualRecurringRevenue(String QuantityName, Decimal QuantityValue) {
            this.QuantityName = QuantityName;
            this.QuantityValue = (QuantityValue != null) ? QuantityValue/1000000 : 0.0;           
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am getting following output Chart on my visual force page:-

[image: Current Output]

I didn’t get legends properly also the color sets for all the bars are same and the bottom text is missing, however in the data source everything is proper, all data are already present there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not see examples of exactly what you want in documentation such as [Building a Complex Chart with Visualforce Charting](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_charting_example.htm).

But you should be able to get part of the way there because [apex:barSeries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_barSeries.htm) supports `colorSet` and `colorsProgressWithinSeries` attributes. It looks like putting the colors there using a true value should give a different color per bar.

In the examples I have seen, the `apex:legend` is typically used to describe the series and you only have one series (your `apex:barSeries`). You are trying to get the legend to repeat the labels of the x-axis and that does not appear to be a supported option.

So I suggest the compromise of using the colored bars and just removing the legend.

**PS**

The code below produces the chart below and demonstrates that just setting `colorsProgressWithinSeries` allows the colors from the `apex:chart` to be used. When experimenting with the size of the chart, I found that the legends are hidden when they don't fit so making the chart bigger is the simplest way to get all the legends shown. One purpose of the legend when displayed is to turn a series on and off so the legend has little value when there is only one series. And there appears to be no option to repurpose the legend to show axis values instead so I think your are out of luck. (Or if the first chart you show was created using `apex:chart` contact whoever created it and ask them.)

[image: Chart from code]

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Annual Recurring Revenue">
        <apex:chart name="AnnualRecurringRevenue" data="{!nvs}" width="400" height="400"
                colorSet="#156F9E,#FF9123,#6BAE4A,#424242,#A4A4A4">
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" grid="true" title="$(Millions)"
                    fields="v"/>
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" grid="false" title="Quarter"
                    fields="n"/>
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="n" yField="v"
                    colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"/>
        </apex:chart>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>

public class ChartController {
    public class Nv {
        public String n { get; private set; }        
        public Decimal v { get; private set; }
        Nv(String n, Decimal v) {
            this.n = n;
            this.v = v;       
        }
    }
    public Nv[] getNvs() {
        return new Nv[] {
            new Nv('Actual', 106.00),
            new Nv('Forecast', 150.56),
            new Nv('Plan', 135.00),
            new Nv('Prior Qtr', 97.00),
            new Nv('Prior Yr', 88.44)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I can put color series with `colorset` and `colorsProgressWithinSeries` attributes, but what I want that it should be automatically reflect from the `<apex:chart>` colorset property. Is there any other alternate logic by which I can achieve all legends and colored bar.
Also at the bottom as you can see there is a text missing I couldn't find out why it is happening, In the back-end the data is retrieved successfully but it is not displayed on the page.

Comment: Well the documentation for apex:chart colorset says "colors to be used by by each child series" and you have exactly one of those. On the missing label, (and assuming the label isn't missing from your data), I had assumed it was a space problem where the algorithm to fit the labels in the available space had done a poor job with a longish piece of label text. There is an apex:chartLabel that has several options that look like they might help (e.g. rotate) or you could shorten the text before it gets to the chart.