# Dynamically pass values for multiple charts in diiferent tabs

Tags: visualforce, charts, tabpanel

Have a graph setup with some simple data coming from a controller.Below is the code for the visualforce page.

```
<apex:page readonly="true">
<apex:tabPanel switchType="server" id="panel">
    <apex:tab label="Pie chart" id="tab1">
        <script>
        var pieData = [{'data1':100, 'name':'Alice'}, {'data1':30, 'name':'Bob'}, {'data1':55, 'name':'Carl'}, {'data1':60, 'name':'Dan'}];
        </script>

        <apex:chart data="pieData" height="200px" width="200px">
            <apex:pieSeries labelField="name" dataField="data1"/>
        </apex:chart>
    </apex:tab>
    <apex:tab label="Line chart" id="tab2">
        <script>
        var barData = [{'data':100, 'label':'UK'}, {'data':30, 'label':'France'}, {'data':55, 'label':'Spain'}, {'data':60, 'label':'Germany'}];
        </script>

        <apex:chart data="barData" height="200px" width="300px">
            <apex:legend position="left"/>
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" title="Nos Leads" grid="true" fields="data" minimum="0">
            </apex:axis>
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" fields="label" title="Country">
                <apex:chartLabel rotate="315"/>
            </apex:axis>
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="label" yField="data"/>
        </apex:chart>
    </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
</apex:page>
```

Can anyone please help me out with the code as to dynamically pass values instead of passing values in script ?

Answer (score 1):

Below is some code that I posted as an answer to this [Salesforce Visualforce Bar Chart problem](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/30215/salesforce-visualforce-bar-chart-problem) question that uses the "controller method reference" `data` option. For naming you are using in your Visualforce, in the class change `v` to `data` and `n` to `name`.

To support multiple charts, you would need to add multiple methods that return different data.

```
<apex:page controller="ChartController">
    <apex:pageBlock title="Annual Recurring Revenue">
        <apex:chart name="AnnualRecurringRevenue" data="{!nvs}" width="400" height="400"
                colorSet="#156F9E,#FF9123,#6BAE4A,#424242,#A4A4A4">
            <apex:axis type="Numeric" position="left" grid="true" title="$(Millions)"
                    fields="v"/>
            <apex:axis type="Category" position="bottom" grid="false" title="Quarter"
                    fields="n"/>
            <apex:barSeries orientation="vertical" axis="left" xField="n" yField="v"
                    colorsProgressWithinSeries="true"/>
        </apex:chart>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:page>

public class ChartController {
    public class Nv {
        public String n { get; private set; }        
        public Decimal v { get; private set; }
        Nv(String n, Decimal v) {
            this.n = n;
            this.v = v;       
        }
    }
    public Nv[] getNvs() {
        return new Nv[] {
            new Nv('Actual', 106.00),
            new Nv('Forecast', 150.56),
            new Nv('Plan', 135.00),
            new Nv('Prior Qtr', 97.00),
            new Nv('Prior Yr', 88.44)
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This worked. But i'm trying to display more than one charts in a tab. So how do i do that.? Did use <apex:tabpanel> and <apex:tab> for above. Say i want to include opportunity chart in this same tab.How will <apex: chart> and </apex:chart> and controller look like ?

Comment: Can anyone please help me out with the above question ?

Comment: Repeat you apex:chart and its content and change the data field to reference a second method on your controller to get different data. (If you want a cleaner solition you could move the apex:chart to a component.) You can decide the layout of the charts by choosing what tag to put around the pair of them.